# Is it possible to distinguish a requestURL as one typed in the address bar to log in a node proxy?

Tags: node.js, http-proxy

I just could not get the http-proxy module to work properly as a forward proxy. It works great as a reverse proxy. Therefore, I have implemented a node-based forward proxy using node's http and net modules. It works fine, both with http and https. I will deal with websockets later. Among other things, I want to log the URLs visited or requested through a browser. In the request object, I do get the URL, but as expected, when a page loads, a zillion other requests are triggered, including AJAX, third-party ads, etc. I do not want to log these.

I know that I can distinguish an AJAX request from the x-requested-with header. I can distinguish requests coming from a browser by examining the user-agent header (though these can be spoofed thru cURL). I want to minimize the log entries.

How do commercial proxies log such info? Or do they just log every request? One way would be to not log any requests within a certain time after the main request presuming that they are all associated with the main request. That would not be technically accurate.

I have researched in this area but did not find any solution. I am not looking for any specific code, just some direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one can know that with precision, but you can find clues such as, "HTTP referer", "x-requested-with" or add your custom headers in each ajax request (squid proxy by default sends a "X-Forwarded-For" which says he is a proxy), but anybody can figure out what headers are you sending for your requests or copy all headers that a common browser sends by default and you will believe it is a person from a browser, but could be a bash cURL sent by a bot.
So, really, you can't know for example, if a request is an AJAX request because the headers aren't mandatory, by default your browser or your framework adds an x-requested-with or useful information to help to "guess" who is performing the request.

Comment: can you provide a list of headers or mechanisms to at least eliminate the known culprits? For example, you said HTTP referer, that helps. I knew of x-requested-with. I am talking about a forward proxy, one that will be used in my small company to keep track of URLs visited. The X-forwarded-For header would therefore not be helpful or so I think.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, I think you could define some rules to ignore urls in logs, such as, any ad server...or if a url ends with .css, .jpg, etc (assets), you know... look for rules to keep the log file clean working mostly with hosts and IPs than http headers, but the ajax header could be a good filter. It is a matter of opening chrome elements inspector and look for patterns.